# Enable SPI flash device's power cycle write protection

Tags: devices, bios, flash-memory, flashrom

Assume that an SPI flash chip is represented as `/dev/spidev`. How do I enable that flash chip's power-cycle write protection?

Comment: have you searched the phrase `Enable SPI flash device power cycle write protection` - to me, a layman, it seems like this depends on the actual device itself, there is no generic method

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a common feature of SPI flash devices.

Comment: are you talking about hardware or software methods?

Comment: @JaromandaX Confusingly, there are `software write protection` and `hardware write protection`, but both are mechanisms of the SPI flash chip.